# SELECT INTO clause in combined queries

Tags: sql, forms, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle forms, and in the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger I am combining two query results using `UNION` operator, my question is how to use the `SELECT INTO` clause to assign the selected values to variables.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on what you want. Paste your query.

Comment: @loki the query is too huge, I tried to simplify the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SELECT statement will be same as what you use in plsql. There's no difference. Note that it can result in too many rows exception.

```
select column_value into l_value
from some_table
where column_value = 'some_value'
union
select column_value
from other_table
where column_value = 'some_value';
```

Comment: Do you mean it will be sufficient if we assigned the value only once

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of cursors in Oracle:
Implicit -- Use the word INTO -- Must return only one record
Explicit -- Don't use INTO    -- Can return multiple records

If you are trying to get many records into an implicit cursor, that is not possible, must use an explicit cursor and check the values with a loop.

DECLARE 
CURSOR c_data IS 
  SELECT a FROM table_name;
BEGIN
  FOR variable IN c_data LOOP
     message('Value is: ' || variable.a);
  END LOOP;

END;